# AutoFill plugin/extension which works for all browsers?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, npapi

I am currently thinking of writing an AutoFill plugin/widget which will take my personal data such as First Name, Last Name etc from a file/javascript and will automatically fill it in web page form. 
    I have read till now to build a plugin which works for all browsers, I have two options:-
    1) To make a Jquery UI widget
    2) To make a NPAPI plugin

Is there any other easier method to develop an autofilling plugin, and which option to take i.e. NPAPI plugin or Jquery widget ? 
Thanks

Comment: Note that reliably filling the many, many variations of forms out there is a pretty hard problem. You should seriously consider whether trying to re-invent that wheel from scratch instead of using form fill that's built in to your browser is actually something you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the two options you mention will allow you to automatically fill in your personal data on all websites.

You'll want to write a *browser extension* (which are [different from plugins](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference/)). As you want to target multiple browsers, you may want to look into frameworks which make that easier, like [crossrider](http://crossrider.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you reckon is better for creating multiple browsers extension, Crossrider or FireBreath ?

Comment: FireBreath is for plugins, so it isn't helpful for you. Crossrider is the one option i know, but i haven't looked extensively.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Much appreciated. Crossrider seems to be good, so I am going to work on it

Comment: I want to make a commercial cross browser extension and I have read that both Crossrider and KangoExtensions require money to make the product commercial.Is there any framework which is both open source and free ?

Comment: I don't know of any, maybe ask a question about that?